I don't know why useEffect runs twice. Please let me know the problem
I'm writing it in a react type script.
But the part that needs to be executed only once is executed twice, so we are having a problem
The first tsx file with the function you use
import React from 'react';
import * as mediasoupClient from 'mediasoup-client';
import { types } from 'mediasoup-client';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import { setupSocket, CustomSocket } from './socket';
import {Consumer,ConsumerOptions} from "mediasoup-client/lib/Consumer";

const mediaType = {
    audio: 'audioType',
    video: 'videoType',
    screen: 'screenType'
};
const _EVENTS = {
    exitRoom: 'exitRoom',
    openRoom: 'openRoom',
    startVideo: 'startVideo',
    stopVideo: 'stopVideo',
    startAudio: 'startAudio',
    stopAudio: 'stopAudio',
    startScreen: 'startScreen',
    stopScreen: 'stopScreen'
};
interface RoomClientProps {
    localMediaEl: HTMLDivElement;
    remoteVideoEl: HTMLDivElement;
    remoteAudioEl: HTMLDivElement;
    socketUrl: string;
    room_id: string;
    name: string;
    successCallback: () => void;
}
interface ConsumeResult {
    consumer: Consumer;
    stream: MediaStream;
    kind: 'video' | 'audio';
}
class RoomClient {
    private name: string;
    private localMediaEl: HTMLVideoElement ;
    private remoteVideoEl: HTMLVideoElement ;
    private remoteAudioEl: HTMLAudioElement ;
    private socket: any;
    private producerTransport: types.Transport | null = null;
    private consumerTransport: types.Transport | null = null;
    private device: mediasoupClient.Device | null = null;
    private room_id: string;
    private isVideoOnFullScreen: boolean = false;
    private isDevicesVisible: boolean = false;
    private consumers: Map<string, types.Consumer> = new Map();
    private producers: Map<string, types.Producer> = new Map();
    private producerLabel: Map<string, string> = new Map();
    private _isOpen: boolean = false;
    private eventListeners: Map<string, Array<() => void>> = new Map();
    static mediaType = {
        audio: 'audioType',
        video: 'videoType',
        screen: 'screenType'
    };

    constructor(
        localMediaEl: HTMLVideoElement,
        remoteVideoEl: HTMLVideoElement,
        remoteAudioEl: HTMLAudioElement,
        mediasoupClientInstance: typeof mediasoupClient,
        socketUrl: string,
        room_id: string,
        name: string,
        successCallback: () => void
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.localMediaEl = localMediaEl;
        this.remoteVideoEl = remoteVideoEl;
        this.remoteAudioEl = remoteAudioEl;
        this.mediasoupClient = mediasoupClientInstance;
        this.socket = setupSocket(io(socketUrl));
        this.room_id = room_id;

        console.log('Mediasoup client', mediasoupClientInstance);

        Object.keys(_EVENTS).forEach((evt) => {
            this.eventListeners.set(evt, []);
        });
        this.createRoom(room_id, name).then(async () => {
            try {
                await this.join(name, room_id);
                this.initSockets();
                this._isOpen = true;
                console.log("create room")
                successCallback();
            } catch(ex) {
                alert('The room is full!');
            }
        });

    }
    private mediasoupClient: typeof mediasoupClient;
    
    async createRoom(room_id: string, name: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.socket.request('createRoom', {
                room_id,
                name
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Create room error:', err);
        }
    }
    async join(name: string, room_id: string) {
        try {
            const e: any = await this.socket.request('join', { name, room_id });
            if (e.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error('The room is full!'));
            }
            console.log('Joined to room', e);
            const data = await this.socket.request('getRouterRtpCapabilities');
            const device = await this.loadDevice(data);
            this.device = device;
            await this.initTransports(device);
            this.socket.emit('getProducers');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to load device:', error);
            alert('Failed to join the room');
        }
    }
    async loadDevice(routerRtpCapabilities: mediasoupClient.types.RtpCapabilities): Promise<mediasoupClient.Device> {
        let device: mediasoupClient.Device;
        console.log("check")

        try {
            device = new mediasoupClient.Device();

        } catch (error: any) {
            if (error.name === 'UnsupportedError') {
                console.error('Browser not supported');
                alert('Browser not supported');
                throw error;
            } else {
                console.error(error);
                throw error;
            }
        }
        await device.load({ routerRtpCapabilities });
        return device;
    }
    async initTransports(device: mediasoupClient.Device) {
        {
            const data = await this.socket.request('createWebRtcTransport', {
                forceTcp: false,
                rtpCapabilities: device.rtpCapabilities
            });

            if (data.error) {
                console.error(data.error);
                return;
            }

            this.producerTransport = device.createSendTransport(data);

            this.producerTransport.on('connect', async ({ dtlsParameters }, callback, errback) => {
                this.socket
                    .request('connectTransport', {
                        dtlsParameters,
                        transport_id: data.id
                    })
                    .then(callback)
                    .catch(errback);
            });

            this.producerTransport.on('produce', async ({ kind, rtpParameters }, callback, errback) => {
                try {
                    const { producer_id } = await this.socket.request('produce', {
                        producerTransportId: this.producerTransport!.id,
                        kind,
                        rtpParameters
                    });
                    callback({ id: producer_id });
                } catch (err:any) {
                    errback(err);
                }
            });

            this.producerTransport.on('connectionstatechange', (state) => {
                switch (state) {
                    case 'connecting':
                        break;
                    case 'connected':
                        break;
                    case 'failed':
                        this.producerTransport!.close();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
        }

        // init consumerTransport
        {
            const data = await this.socket.request('createWebRtcTransport', {
                forceTcp: false
            });

            if (data.error) {
                console.error(data.error);
                return;
            }

            this.consumerTransport = device.createRecvTransport(data);
            this.consumerTransport.on('connect', ({ dtlsParameters }, callback, errback) => {
                this.socket
                    .request('connectTransport', {
                        transport_id: this.consumerTransport!.id,
                        dtlsParameters
                    })
                    .then(callback)
                    .catch(errback);
            });

            this.consumerTransport.on('connectionstatechange', async (state) => {
                switch (state) {
                    case 'connecting':
                        break;
                    case 'connected':
                        break;
                    case 'failed':
                        this.consumerTransport!.close();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    initSockets() {
        this.socket.on('rule', (data: any) => {
            console.log(new Date().toISOString(), data);
        });

        this.socket.on('consumerClosed', ({ consumer_id }: { consumer_id: string }) => {
            console.log('Closing consumer:', consumer_id);
            this.removeConsumer(consumer_id);
        });

        this.socket.on('addUser', (data: any) => {
            console.log('New user:', data);
        });

        this.socket.on('swapUser', (data: any) => {
            console.log('Swap user:', data);
        });

        this.socket.on('removeUser', (data: any) => {
            console.log('Remove user:', data);
        });

        this.socket.on('newProducers', async (data: any) => {
            console.log('New producers', data);
            for (let { producer_id } of data) {
                await this.consume(producer_id);
            }
        });

        this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            this.exit(true);
        });
    }
    async produce(type: string, deviceId: string | null = null) {
        let mediaConstraints: any = {};
        let audio = false;
        let screen = false;
        switch (type) {
            case mediaType.audio:
                mediaConstraints = {
                    audio: {
                        deviceId: deviceId
                    },
                    video: false
                };
                audio = true;
                break;
            case mediaType.video:
                mediaConstraints = {
                    audio: false,
                    video: {
                        width: {
                            min: 640,
                            ideal: 640
                        },
                        height: {
                            min: 480,
                            ideal: 480
                        },
                        deviceId: deviceId
                    }
                };
                break;
            case mediaType.screen:
                mediaConstraints = false;
                screen = true;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        if (!this.device!.canProduce('video') && !audio) {
            console.error('Cannot produce video');
            return;
        }
        if (this.producerLabel.has(type)) {
            console.log('Producer already exists for this type ' + type);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Media constraints:', mediaConstraints);
        let stream;
        try {
            stream = screen ? await (navigator.mediaDevices as any).getDisplayMedia() : await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints);
            console.log(navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints());
            const track = audio ? stream.getAudioTracks()[0] : stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            const params = {
                track
            };
            const producer = await this.producerTransport!.produce(params);
            console.log('Producer', producer);

            this.producers.set(producer.id, producer);

            let elem: HTMLVideoElement;
            if (!audio) {
                elem = document.createElement('video');
                elem.srcObject = stream;
                elem.id = producer.id;
                elem.playsInline = false;
                elem.autoplay = true;
                elem.className = 'vid';
                this.localMediaEl.appendChild(elem);
                console.log(elem+ "일단은 눈에 띄어야한다")
            }

            producer.on('trackended', () => {
                this.closeProducer(type);
            });

            producer.on('transportclose', () => {
                console.log('Producer transport closed');
                if (!audio) {
                    elem!.parentNode!.removeChild(elem!);
                }
                this.producers.delete(producer.id);
            });

            producer.on('@close', () => {
                console.log('Closing producer');
                if (!audio) {
                    elem!.parentNode!.removeChild(elem!);
                }
                this.producers.delete(producer.id);
            });

            this.producerLabel.set(type, producer.id);

            switch (type) {
                case mediaType.audio:
                    this.event(_EVENTS.startAudio);
                    break;
                case mediaType.video:
                    this.event(_EVENTS.startVideo);
                    break;
                case mediaType.screen:
                    this.event(_EVENTS.startScreen);
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    async consume(producer_id: string) {
        try {

            const { consumer, stream, kind } = await this.getConsumeStream(producer_id);
            this.consumers.set(consumer.id, consumer);
            let elem: HTMLVideoElement | HTMLAudioElement;
            if (kind === 'video') {
                elem = document.createElement('video');
                elem.srcObject = stream;
                elem.id = consumer.id;

                if ("playsInline" in elem) {
                    elem.playsInline = false;
                } // For video
                elem.autoplay = true;
                elem.className = 'vid';
                this.remoteVideoEl.appendChild(elem);
                
            } else {
                elem = document.createElement('audio');
                elem.srcObject = stream;
                elem.id = consumer.id;
                elem.autoplay = true;
                // Handle playsInline property for audio
                if ("playsInline" in elem) {
                    // Some browsers might support it, so set it to false if available
                    elem.playsInline = false;
                }
                this.remoteAudioEl.appendChild(elem);
                
            }

            consumer.on('trackended', () => {
                this.removeConsumer(consumer.id);
            });

            consumer.on('transportclose', () => {
                this.removeConsumer(consumer.id);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error consuming stream:', error);
        }
    }

    async getConsumeStream(producerId: string): Promise<ConsumeResult> {
        const { rtpCapabilities } = this.device!;
        const data = await this.socket.request('consume', {
            rtpCapabilities,
            consumerTransportId: this.consumerTransport!.id,
            producerId
        });
        const { id, kind, rtpParameters } = data;

        const consumer = await this.consumerTransport!.consume({
            id,
            producerId,
            kind,
            rtpParameters,
        });

        const stream = new MediaStream();
        stream.addTrack(consumer.track);

        return {
            consumer,
            stream,
            kind
        };
    }
   
}

export default RoomClient;


Files with functions used by setting.tsx
import { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import RoomClient from "./RoomClient";
import { types } from 'mediasoup-client';

export function joinRoom(name: string, room_id: string, audioSelect: HTMLOptionElement, videoSelect: HTMLOptionElement, localMediaEl: HTMLVideoElement,
                         remoteVideoEl: HTMLVideoElement,
                         remoteAudioEl: HTMLAudioElement,
                         mediasoupClientInstance: any,
                         socketUrl: string,
                         successCallback: () => void) {
    if (rc && rc.isOpen()) {
        console.log('Already connected to a room');
    } else {
        console.log('joinjoinhjoin');
        initEnumerateDevices(audioSelect,videoSelect);
        rc = new RoomClient(localMediaEl, remoteVideoEl, remoteAudioEl, mediasoupClientInstance, socketUrl, room_id, name,  successCallback);
    }
}
export function initEnumerateDevices(audioSelect: HTMLOptionElement, videoSelect: HTMLOptionElement) {
    console.log("initinitinit0")
    // Many browsers, without the consent of getUserMedia, cannot enumerate the devices.
    if (isEnumerateDevices) return;

    const constraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: true
    };

    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((stream: MediaStream) => {
            enumerateDevices(audioSelect, videoSelect);
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track: MediaStreamTrack) {
                track.stop();
            });
            console.log("initinitinit")
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
            console.error('Access denied for audio/video: ', err);
        });
}

export function enumerateDevices(audioSelect: HTMLOptionElement, videoSelect: HTMLOptionElement) {
    // Load mediaDevice options
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) =>
        devices.forEach((device) => {
            let el = null;
            if ('audioinput' === device.kind) {
                el = audioSelect;
            } else if ('videoinput' === device.kind) {
                el = videoSelect;
            }
            if (!el) return;

            let option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = device.deviceId || '';
            option.innerText = device.label || '';

            el.appendChild(option);
            isEnumerateDevices = true;
        })
    );
}

Before going to the discussion room, setting.tsx
    const onClickCreate = async () => {
        navigate('/debateRoom', {
            state: {
                name,
                selectedMicDevice: selectedMicDeviceRef.current?.value,
                selectedAudioDevice: selectedAudioDeviceRef.current?.value,
                selectedVideoDevice: selectedVideoDeviceRef.current?.value
            }
        });
        console.log(selectedAudioDeviceRef.current);
        console.log(selectedVideoDeviceRef.current);
        if (selectedAudioDeviceRef.current&&selectedVideoDeviceRef.current) {
            console.log(remoteVideoEl+"remotevideo확인")
            joinRoom(name, "frontend", selectedAudioDeviceRef.current, selectedVideoDeviceRef.current, localMediaEl, remoteVideoEl, remoteAudioEl, mediasoupClient, "http://localhost:3001", successCallback);

        }

        console.log(name);
    };
 

Debit room tsx file where the problem occurs
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {useLocation, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import "./DebateRoom.css"
import DebateFin from "./DebateFin/DebateFin";
import RoomClient from "../../socket/RoomClient";
import {rc} from "../../socket/socket";

interface DebateRoomProps {
    onLeave: () => void;
}

const DebateRoom: React.FC<DebateRoomProps> = ({onLeave}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const { selectedMicDevice, selectedAudioDevice, selectedVideoDevice } = location.state;
    const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

    const leave = () => {
        navigate('/dashboard');
    };
  
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const initVideo = async () => {
            try {
                console.log("device start")
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
                if (videoRef.current) {
                   
                    console.log(selectedVideoDevice + " video");
                    console.log(selectedAudioDevice + " audio");
                    await rc.produce(RoomClient.mediaType.video, selectedVideoDevice);
                    await rc.produce(RoomClient.mediaType.audio, selectedAudioDevice);
                    videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing local media:', error);
            }
        };

        initVideo();
    }, []);

    
    
    return (
        <div>       
            <div className="AteamArea">
                <div className="A1">
                    <video className="Cam" ref={videoRef} autoPlay width="526px" height="332px" ></video>
                 
                </div>       
            </div>
           
    );
};
export default DebateRoom;

I have a problem in debateRoom.tsx where useEffect with produce runs 2 times. What is the problem?
It's the part that runs twice in debateRoom
useEffect(() => {
        const initVideo = async () => {
            try {
                console.log("device start")
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true });
                if (videoRef.current) {
                    console.log(selectedVideoDevice + " video");
                    console.log(selectedAudioDevice + " audio");
                    await rc.produce(RoomClient.mediaType.video, selectedVideoDevice);
                    await rc.produce(RoomClient.mediaType.audio, selectedAudioDevice);
                    videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing local media:', error);
            }
        };
        initVideo();
    }, []);

This part should be done only once

You should greatly reduce the amount of code you're posting. It's way too much for someone to look through. Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

I'm sorry about that. I tried to shorten it as much as possible.

Welcome to StackOverflow. As your dependency-array is empty, the useEffect should only run on first rendering. Are you sure, you're not using strict mode? Did you remove it explicitly? It's on by default.

Maybe double check if you find sth. like <React.StrictMode> in your index.js file. Or build for production and see if the useEffect still runs twice.

This is an effect that you'll only notice in development. When you deploy to production, it will only run once.
